# Spread pairs change when using the rendition display on Epub.js

Tags: epub, epub.js

Spread pairs change when using the code like this.
`rendition.display(epubCFI)`
If you give some epubCFI to this function from second page, it takes second page right to left. It was already visible on the right. This situation changes the epub page placements compeletely.